# Using TemplateField in Gridview with jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I'm using a Gridview to display a download link LinkButton inside of a TemplateField in ASP.NET (webforms). The header of the first column is being displayed in the body of all rows on the second column and I get a Non-table node initialisation error.
[image]
The table displays correctly (without jQuery Datatables styling) when jQuery is removed so I would assume the problem would be in the jQuery used to prepend the headers. However, if I remove the TemplateField, the table displays correctly so that leaves me to think it has something to do with the TemplateField. Here is the aspx page:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="tblDownload" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped dataTables_scrollHead" Visible="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FILE_NAME" HeaderText="File Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" SortExpression="Download">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ID" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
var Table1 = $("[id*=tblDownload]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("[id*=tblDownload] tr:first"))).DataTable({

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `ClientIDMode="Static"`in the GridView table.